# Dynamically generating a dropdown using json data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, dynamic, drop-down-menu

I have developed a script that receives json data from a php script using $.getJSON. The JSON data looks like '[{"options":"smart_exp"},{"options":"user_intf"},{"options":"blahblah"}] '

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
//$('document').ready(function() { 

function Preload() {
  $.getJSON("http://localhost/conn_mysql.php", function(jsonData){  
  $.each(jsonData, function(i,j)
  { alert(j.options);});
});} 

// });

</script></head>
<body onLoad="Preload()">
</body>
</html>
```

I also developed a script that dynamically generates a dropdown list using an array.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script language="javascript">
var myarray = new Array("apples","oranges","bananas","Peac");
function populate()
{ for (i=0; i<myarray.length; i++)
{
document.form1.fruits.options[i]=new Option(myarray[i], i);
}
}
</script>
</HEAD>
<body onload="populate();">
<form name="form1">
My favourite fruit is :
<select name="fruits" />
</form>
</body>
</HTML>
```

Now I need to dynamically build a dropdown list using data returned by getJson but I am having trouble in merging both. I will be very thankful for the help. Here is what I tried to do but its not working.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    //$('document').ready(function() { 

    function Preload() {
    var myarray = new Array();
    $.getJSON("http://localhost/conn_mysql.php", function(jsonData){  
    $.each(jsonData, function(i,j)
    { myarray = j.options;});});
    for (i=0; i<myarray.length; i++)
    { document.form1.fruits.options[i]=new Option(myarray[i]); } 
    } 
    // });
   </script></head>
   <body onLoad="Preload()">
   <form name="form1">
   My favourite fruit is :
   <select name="fruits" />
   </form>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `.getJSON()` uses a callback, meaning that the code executed as the second argument of `.getJSON()` won't necessarily have been called by the time your `for` loop runs. It runs once the server responds with your `conn_mysql.php` JSON data. Try nesting it:

```
function Preload() {
    $.getJSON("http://localhost/conn_mysql.php", function (jsonData) {
        $.each(jsonData, function (i, j) {
            document.form1.fruits.options[i] = new Option(j.options);
        });
    });
}
```

You should be aware of the structure of your `jsonData`. Here, this would only work if the structure were:

```
[
    { options: "item 1" },
    { options: "item 2" },
    { options: "item 3" },
]
```

It loops through the entire object, finding each element of the array, then looks for that element's `options` property. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Grate, u r grate ...... thanX a Lot. Its working now with ur code. One problem is it works only in IE so far, do not work in firefox. I think I need to make //$('document').ready(function() working that is commented now in my this code as I was not able to fix it. Can u see it, I think it has only bracees problem. Can u kindly tell me one more thing, can PURE i.e. a JS rendering engine be used in such case. Provided I have no info so far about JS rendering engines. thanX a thousand again clarkf :-) –

Comment: @babar - I'm not sure what you're asking. If you're asking about the pure templating library (http://beebole.com/pure/), sure, it could be used here. You'd need to modify your JSON data a little in the PHP script (I think, I'm unfamiliar with pure). Check out the documentation?

Answer (score 2):

i'm not sure what your json data looks like, but maybe you need something like this:

```
function Preload() {
  $.getJSON("http://localhost/conn_mysql.php", function(jsonData){  
    $.each(jsonData, function(i,j){ 
      $('#ID-OF-YOUR-SELECT-ELEMENT').append(
        $('<option></option>').val(j.value).html(j.text)
      );
    }
  );
});}
```

j.value = the value of the option you want to add
j.text = the name of the option you want to add (what the user sees)

Comment: it looks like  [{"options":"smart_exp"},{"options":"user_intf"},{"options":"blahblah"}]

Answer (score 0):

One problem I see is that in your each loop, you're just assigning j.options to myarray instead of adding it to the array. Change to:

```
myarray.push(j.options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer / Firefox issue is possible due to the page encoding type - recommend trying utf-8.